# Mysql select query for getting current user post and followed friend post

Tags: mysql, sql

My current select query statement:

```
 SELECT
    T.postID, 
    T.message, 
    T.time,
    U.userID,
    U.name, 
    U.username, 
    U.picture_url
 FROM
    post AS T,
    users AS U 
 WHERE
    T.postID = '$uid' //$uid holds the id of the current logged in user
    order by T.postID DESC;
```

My select query outputs the post of the current logged in user but I want to output the post of the followed user of the current logged in user as well, how can I do it?

USER TABLE:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userID     |int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       |VARCHAR(60) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username   |VARCHAR(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| picture_url|VARCHAR(200)| NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

POST TABLE:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| postID     |int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pUserID    |int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message    |VARCHAR(140)| NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time       |datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

FOLLOW USER TABLE

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fid        |int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userId1    |int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userId2    |int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Try writing your query with explicit `join` syntax and you will probably fix your problem.

Comment: How is post table related to the other two tables?

Comment: @Srikanth I'm sorry, I forgot to include the pUserID at the POST TABLE. I edited my question now. -- The POST TABLE holds the post of each user and the ID of each user who posted (pUserID)

Comment: Try to post sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is recommended to use explicit [JOINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) over [implicit CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join)

Try the following query.

```
 SELECT
    T.postID, 
    T.message, 
    T.time,
    U.userID,
    U.name, 
    U.username, 
    U.picture_url,
    F.userID2,
 FROM
    users AS U  
 INNER JOIN 
    follow_user AS F
 ON U.userID = F.userId1    
 INNER JOIN 
    post AS T
 ON T.pUserID = U.userID OR T.pUserID = F.userId2 
 WHERE
    U.userID = '$uid' //$uid holds the id of the current logged in user
    order by T.postID DESC;
```

Comment: i have a similar query with similar table structure, but i don't need to get user U table involved not sure i how should i modify query

Comment: @al404IT What do you mean  `don't need to get user U table involved` What is the expected output and columns required in it?

Comment: i need to output only  T.postID,  T.message,  T.time but i still need user + friends posts

Comment: Then keep only those columns and remove the other columns from the select. If this not want you want I guess Its not very clear about what you want and Its better post a new question referring to this question and mentioning what you want and how it different than this question.