# MYSQL Query - Get current user's posts and the user's he's following posts

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query to get the current user's posts and the posts of the people he is following. Like most social networks do in their home page.

I know how to query all of the current user's posts, but I am struggling to get the user's he's following posts.

I saw this other question [Mysql select query for getting current user post and followed friend post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428551/mysql-select-query-for-getting-current-user-post-and-followed-friend-post?rq=1)

But the answer there isn't really helping me...

Here's is my query so far:

```
SELECT P.id, 
P.caption,
P.date,
U.id,
U.fullname,
U.username,
F.IdOtherUser
FROM USERS AS U
INNER JOIN Activity AS F
ON U.id = F.id
INNER JOIN Posts AS P 
ON P.id = U.id OR P.id = F.IdOtherUser
WHERE P.id = 145
ORDER BY P.id DESC
```

145 = current user.

Activity.IdOtherUser = the user '145' is following

Activity.id = will be '145' the current user

If anyone can help me sort this I'd appreciate it alot!

Cannot seem to understand it fully, as I am quite new to MYSQL...

**Fix**

```
(SELECT P.id as postid, 
        P.caption,
        P.date,
        U.id as userid,
        U.fullname,
        U.username,
        coalesce(Activity.LikeCNT,0),
        Activity.CurrentUserLiked
        FROM USERS AS U
        INNER JOIN Posts AS P 
        ON P.id = U.id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Activity.uuidPost) LikeCNT, Activity.uuidPost, Activity.id, sum(CASE WHEN Activity.id = 145 then 1 else 0 end) as CurrentUserLiked
        FROM Activity Activity
        WHERE type = 'like' 
        GROUP BY Activity.uuidPost) Activity
        ON Activity.uuidPost = P.uuid
        AND Activity.id = U.id
        WHERE U.id = 145)
UNION
(SELECT P.id, 
        P.caption,
        P.date,
        U.id,
        U.fullname,
        U.username,
        coalesce(Activity.LikeCNT,0),
        Activity.CurrentUserLiked
        FROM Activity AS A
        INNER JOIN USERS AS U 
        ON A.IdOtherUser=U.id
        INNER JOIN Posts AS P 
        ON P.id = U.id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Activity.uuidPost) LikeCNT, Activity.uuidPost, Activity.id, sum(CASE WHEN Activity.id = 145 then 1 else 0 end) as CurrentUserLiked
    FROM Activity Activity
    WHERE type = 'like' 
    GROUP BY Activity.uuidPost) Activity
    ON Activity.uuidPost = P.uuid
    AND Activity.id = U.id
    WHERE A.id = 145)
```

Comment: Hmm, that answer seems to be incorrect. `T.postID = '$uid' //$uid holds the id of the current logged in user` -> postID the id of the post, not the id of the user. You have the same issue: P.id has nothing to do with the current user

Comment: @Shadow Oh so should it be u.id = 145?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Nice spot!

Comment: @Shadow Ay idea why it return 94 results when it should be 25?

Comment: I hope you do not expect me to be a mind reader that can answer this question without knowing your data!

Comment: @Shadow I removed F.IdOtherUser which fixed that, but users detail is the same as 145's for all Posts

Comment: Yep, that's expected, since you are using `u.id = 145`

Comment: @Shadow Any idea how I could change that to get the correct user details for each post?

Comment: If you drop `OR P.id = F.IdOtherUser`, then your are not going to get the posts of those users that user 145 follows

Comment: @Shadow Well I dont want that do I? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the posts a given user (id=145) and all the users it follows posts, along with the user details for each post, I would rewrite the query to use `union` instead of the or, thus simplifying the logic. The 1st select gets the posts of the given user, the 2nd gets the posts of the users it is following:

```
(SELECT P.id as postid, 
       P.caption,
       P.date,
       U.id as userid,
       U.fullname,
       U.username,
FROM USERS AS U
INNER JOIN Posts AS P ON P.userid = U.id
WHERE U.id = 145)
UNION
(SELECT P.id, 
       P.caption,
       P.date,
       U.id,
       U.fullname,
       U.username,
FROM Activity AS A
INNER JOIN USERS AS U ON A.IdOtherUser=U.id
INNER JOIN Posts AS P ON P.userid = U.id
WHERE A.id = 145)
ORDER BY postid DESC
```

Assumptions:

1. Activity.id field represents the user, who follows the other user. If not, you need to change the field name to the appropriate one.
2. Invented the userid field of Posts table representing the user who posted the post. Pls use the correct field name in its place.

Comment: Fantastic mate.. Don't worry I used the correct field name in it's place!

Comment: Hey, my I ask you 1 last thing... Could you give me your oppinion on my final query, I added it to my question?

Comment: I do not really know what type of an answer your are expecting, to be honest.

Comment: Just is it good, or is it bad and could cause issues in the future...Possibly when the server grows?

Comment: Is it too long? or doesn't that matter?

Comment: Do excuse me, I am new to MYSQL and server stuff...Just trying to learn as much as I can

Comment: I also noticed that the counts doesn't work correctly...I guest I just need 1 count for both queries and not 2 counts, 1 in each... But that will probably end up as another stackOverFlow question

Comment: Well, if you know that certain parts are not producing the expected results, the query cannot be that good, can it (and yes, that' a different question on SO)? Length? Even on SO it is easy to find queries those code is a lot longer than this one. Performance? That's a completely different question requiring lots of additional information on your side (not to mention tweaking the server settings, but that's not really SO question).

Comment: Alright well thanks for you time, do you know any tutorial's for learning more about server side security and performance?

Comment: 1) Tutorials are not really going to help you in these areas. They are way too complex for that. 2) Asking for tutorials is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Ok, I'm probably pushing it here! But where would you reccomend is the best place to learn the basics of security and performance server side?