# MYSQL Query - Include posts of people I am following in my current query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the posts that belong to the user's I follow in my current query.

At the moment I am getting: **Current user's posts - like count for each post & and comments.**

I need to have this result though: **Current user's posts - People I am following post's - like count for each post & comments.**

The final result is like most social network homepages do. They get your posts and the posts of the people you are following / or your friends posts.

This is my current query:

```
 SELECT
      Posts.id
    , Posts.uuid
    , max(case when rcom.row_number = 1 then rcom.comment end) Comment_one
    , max(case when rcom.row_number = 2 then rcom.comment end) Comment_two
    , Posts.caption
    , Posts.path
    , Posts.`date`
    , USERS.id
    , USERS.username
    , USERS.fullname
    , USERS.profileImage
    , COALESCE(A.LikeCNT, 0) num_likes
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN USERS ON Posts.id = 145
            AND USERS.id = 145
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT
                COUNT(A.uuidPost) LikeCNT
              , A.UUIDPost
          FROM Activity A
          WHERE type = 'like'
          GROUP BY
                A.UUIDPOST
          ) A ON A.UUIDPost = Posts.uuid 
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            @row_num := IF(@prev_value=UUIDPOST,@row_num+1,1) as row_number
          , comment
          , uuidPost
          , `date`
          , @prev_value := UUIDPOST
      FROM Activity
      CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @row_num := 1, @prev_value := '' collate utf8_unicode_ci  ) xy
      WHERE type = 'comment'
      ORDER BY
            uuidPost
          , `date` DESC
      ) rcom ON rcom.uuidPost  = Posts.UUID
            AND rcom.row_number <= 2
GROUP BY
      Posts.id
    , Posts.uuid
    , Posts.caption
    , Posts.path
    , Posts.`date`
    , USERS.id
    , USERS.username
    , USERS.fullname
    , USERS.profileImage
    , COALESCE(A.LikeCNT, 0)

      ORDER BY date DESC

      ;
```

**How are my followers stored?**

I store my followers in the "Activity" table like so: **id**(currentUser) - **idOtherUser**(Person I am following) - **type**(which is equal to "Follow").

That is it. Here is a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b04d/1) with some sample data.

Any further questions please let me know.

Comment: I though I have already answered this question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286026/mysql-query-get-current-users-posts-and-the-users-hes-following-posts

Comment: @Shadow Yeh you did help me but since I changed the query, and I am getting the comments, I don't think It would be a great idea to UNION that code....I don't think that would be a great query...

Comment: @Shadow I could be mistaken, I don't know. Would love to hear your oppinion!

Comment: You changed your code, but you have not changed your db structure, therefore the same logic applies.

Comment: @Shadow but if I did a UNION and with the same code above but getting the other users, I would still have the problem with the like/comments. As with that code at the moment if current user has not liked the post, it counts the likes, but if the current user does like that post then the count goes from i.e "10" back down to "1" and only counts that users like...Not sure how clear that sounds.

Comment: 1) It does not sound clear to me 2) You have not mentioned this in your question.

Comment: Well I didn't mention It in my question as I wasn't planning on using UNION but if thats the only decent solution then I'll hve too. Regarding not being clear: i.e user2 likes post1 and user1 see's post1, NOW post1 has "1 like count" But if user1 likes post1 too then the like count should be "2 like count" BUT it stay "1 like count" and only counts the current users(user1) like!

Comment: This is the only follow data at the sqlfidde: `(123, 145, 'a105', '', 'Follow', '', '2016-07-10 00:00:00')`  are you certain that is correct? (the UUIDPost is null for that row) It seems then that a follow row only needs to relate to a user, not to a specific post?

Comment: Is the follow row meant as two-way relation? So if I follow user 12323 he also follows me, or would he get an own entry in the table?

Comment: @Used_By_Already yes it is related to a user no specific post. the id's are related to the posts.

Comment: @Philipp If I follow you 1 row gets added, and if you follow me back another row get added...Probably not the best setup!

Comment: @Jack It's the right setup if you want it to be this way. I would find it weird to follow someone just because he follows me.

Comment: @Philipp Ok thanks thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for.

I assumed every user has to hit the follow button himself. AlsoThis is written from the perspective from user 145, you have to change the `WHERE`-clauses. In your sample there is no relation for user 145 following user 123, I added it to test the query.

I removed the `Users.id` from the select list, as it is the same as `Posts.id` anyways.

Some sample data for the like count would have been nice, don't know how to fill your tables.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Posts.id,
            Posts.uuid,
            max(
                CASE
                WHEN rcom.row_number = 1 THEN
                    rcom.commentText
                END
            ) Comment_one,
max(
    CASE
    WHEN rcom.row_number = 1 THEN
        rcom.commentUserName
    END
) Comment_one_user,
            max(
                CASE
                WHEN rcom.row_number = 2 THEN
                    rcom.commentText
                END
            ) Comment_two,
max(
    CASE
    WHEN rcom.row_number = 2 THEN
        rcom.commentUserName
    END
) Comment_two_user,
            Posts.`date`,
            USERS.username,
            USERS.profileImage,
            COALESCE (A.LikeCNT, 0) num_likes
        FROM
            Posts
        INNER JOIN USERS ON Posts.id = USERS.id 
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                COUNT(A.uuidPost) LikeCNT,
                A.UUIDPost
            FROM
                Activity A
            WHERE
                type = 'like'
            GROUP BY
                A.UUIDPOST
        ) A ON A.UUIDPost = Posts.uuid
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    @row_num :=
                IF (
                    @prev_value = UUIDPOST ,@row_num + 1,
                    1
                ) AS row_number,
                commentText,
                uuidPost,
Activity.`date`,
                @prev_value := UUIDPOST,
USERS.id AS commentUserId,
USERS.username AS commentUserName
            FROM
                Activity
                        CROSS JOIN (
                                SELECT
                                        @row_num := 1,
                                        @prev_value := '' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
                                ) xy
INNER JOIN USERS ON USERS.id = Activity.id
                        WHERE
                                type = 'comment'
                        ORDER BY
                                uuidPost,
                                `date` DESC
            ) rcom ON rcom.uuidPost = Posts.UUID AND rcom.row_number <= 2

WHERE Posts.id = 145

        GROUP BY
            Posts.id,
            Posts.uuid,
            Posts.`date`,
            USERS.username,
            USERS.profileImage,
            COALESCE (A.LikeCNT, 0)
        UNION
            SELECT
                Posts.id,
                Posts.uuid,
            max(
                CASE
                WHEN rcom.row_number = 1 THEN
                    rcom.commentText
                END
            ) Comment_one,
max(
    CASE
    WHEN rcom.row_number = 1 THEN
        rcom.commentUserName
    END
) Comment_one_user,
            max(
                CASE
                WHEN rcom.row_number = 2 THEN
                    rcom.commentText
                END
            ) Comment_two,
max(
    CASE
    WHEN rcom.row_number = 2 THEN
        rcom.commentUserName
    END
) Comment_two_user,
                Posts.`date`,
                USERS.username,
                USERS.profileImage,
                COALESCE (A.LikeCNT, 0) num_likes
            FROM
                Posts
            INNER JOIN Activity ON Activity.type = 'Follow' AND Posts.id = Activity.IdOtherUser
            INNER JOIN USERS ON Activity.IdOtherUser = USERS.id
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(A.uuidPost) LikeCNT,
                    A.UUIDPost
                FROM
                    Activity A
                WHERE
                    type = 'like'
                GROUP BY
                    A.UUIDPOST
            ) A ON A.UUIDPost = Posts.uuid
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    @row_num :=
                IF (
                    @prev_value = UUIDPOST ,@row_num + 1,
                    1
                ) AS row_number,
                commentText,
                uuidPost,
Activity.`date`,
                @prev_value := UUIDPOST,
USERS.id AS commentUserId,
USERS.username AS commentUserName
            FROM
                Activity
                        CROSS JOIN (
                                SELECT
                                        @row_num := 1,
                                        @prev_value := '' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
                                ) xy
INNER JOIN USERS ON USERS.id = Activity.id
                        WHERE
                                type = 'comment'
                        ORDER BY
                                uuidPost,
                                `date` DESC
            ) rcom ON rcom.uuidPost = Posts.UUID AND rcom.row_number <= 2

WHERE Activity.id = 145

            GROUP BY
                Posts.id,
                Posts.uuid,
                Posts.`date`,
                USERS.username,
                USERS.profileImage,
                COALESCE (A.LikeCNT, 0)
    ) AS posts
ORDER BY
    posts.`date` DESC;
```

**edit**

After tidying up the indentation and joining the comments + likecount after selecting the posts:

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.uuid,
    max(CASE WHEN rcom.row_number = 1 THEN rcom.commentText END) AS Comment_one,
    max(CASE WHEN rcom.row_number = 1 THEN rcom.commentUserName END) Comment_one_user,
    max(CASE WHEN rcom.row_number = 2 THEN rcom.commentText END) Comment_two,
    max(CASE WHEN rcom.row_number = 2 THEN rcom.commentUserName END) Comment_two_user,
    posts.`date`,
    posts.username,
    posts.profileImage,
    COALESCE(A.LikeCNT) AS likes
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Posts.id,
        Posts.uuid,
        Posts.`date`,
        USERS.username,
        USERS.profileImage
    FROM
        Posts
    INNER JOIN USERS 
        ON Posts.id = USERS.id 
    WHERE 
        Posts.id = 145
    GROUP BY
        Posts.id,
        Posts.uuid,
        Posts.`date`,
        USERS.username,
        USERS.profileImage
    UNION
        SELECT
            Posts.id,
            Posts.uuid,
            Posts.`date`,
            USERS.username,
            USERS.profileImage
        FROM
            Posts
        INNER JOIN Activity 
            ON Activity.type = 'Follow' AND Posts.id = Activity.IdOtherUser
        INNER JOIN USERS 
            ON Activity.IdOtherUser = USERS.id
        WHERE 
            Activity.id = 145
        GROUP BY
            Posts.id,
            Posts.uuid,
            Posts.`date`,
            USERS.username,
            USERS.profileImage
) AS posts
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(A.uuidPost) LikeCNT,
        A.UUIDPost
    FROM 
        Activity A
    WHERE
        type = 'like'
    GROUP BY
        A.UUIDPOST
) AS A ON A.UUIDPost = posts.uuid

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        commentText,
        uuidPost,
        `date`,
        commentUserId,
        commentUserName,
        @row_num := IF (@prev_value = UUIDPOST, @row_num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @prev_value := UUIDPOST
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            commentText,
            uuidPost,
            Activity.`date`,
            USERS.id AS commentUserId,
            USERS.username AS commentUserName
        FROM
            Activity
        INNER JOIN USERS 
            ON USERS.id = Activity.id
        WHERE
            type = 'comment'
        ORDER BY
            uuidPost,
            `date` DESC
        ) AS comments

        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT
                @row_num := 1,
                @prev_value := '' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
        ) AS xy
    ) rcom 
        ON rcom.uuidPost = posts.UUID AND rcom.row_number <= 2
GROUP BY 
    posts.uuid
ORDER BY
    posts.`date` DESC
```

Comment: Nice seems to be working, any idea how I could get the username and date for the comments too? the username is in the USERS table so you'd have to use the id's like for getting posts username... I guess

Comment: You can add a join when you are getting the comments. Added it to the query and messed up the indenting so you can see the changes I made.

Comment: @Jack added the new query