# How to write a query which gets the posts made by users the current user follows

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

So I have a blog application where users can make posts and follow each other. I'd like to implement a way to build the user's feed by presenting posts made by users they follow.

I have found identical questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286026/mysql-query-get-current-users-posts-and-the-users-hes-following-posts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428551/mysql-select-query-for-getting-current-user-post-and-followed-friend-post) but I am relatively new to SQL and can only understand about half of the solutions provided. Therefore I can't really figure out a way to apply them to my specific tables.

Here are my tables:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username  string   `json:"username"`
    Password  string   `json:"password"`
    Followers []*User  `gorm:"many2many:user_followers"`
}
```

```
// this is the join table for the many-to-many, user-followers relationship
type UserFollowers struct {
    UserId     string  `json:"user_id"`
    FollowerId string  `json:"follower_id"`
}
```

```
type Post struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId  string  `json:"user_id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Caption string  `json:"caption"`
    Media   string  `json:"media"`
}
```

I have built a query which successfully get a user's followings which I believe is a good starting point but after this I have no idea what to do. It looks like this:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username 
FROM users JOIN user_followers 
ON user_followers.follower_id = "id of current user"
AND user_followers.user_id = users.id
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Take some time to read about chain-joins: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-multiple-joins-for-beginners-with-examples/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-joins-in-sql/

Comment: please show your queries to get a user's posts and to get a user's followings.  your schema would be more useful than the go structs (output of `show create table yourtablename` for the relevant tables)

Answer (score 0):

Your target query would look something like this -

```sql
SELECT posts.user_id, posts.title, posts.caption, posts.media
FROM posts JOIN user_followers ON user_followers.follower_id = posts.user_id
WHERE user_followers.user_id = "id of current user"
```